# Navigation not staying inside div

Tags: html, css

My Navigation in my HTML document is not staying with the assigned div. I placed my navigation inside of a div and it is not staying inside of it. I would also like to know why my header is stretching right so far. The navigation should be on the same line as the header not below it. They are both within the same div! So why are they not showing it?
Plz help.
Thanks!

```css
.navigation-bar {
  bottom: 0px;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .74);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.brand-text {
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  float: none;
  clear: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease;
  transition: color 700ms ease;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.brand-text:hover {
  color: #858585;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-menu {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.nav-link {
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px none #858585;
  -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease, border 700ms ease;
  transition: color 700ms ease, border 700ms ease;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-link:hover {
  border-style: none;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #858585;
  color: #858585;
}
.nav-link.w--current {
  border-style: none none solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease;
  transition: color 700ms ease;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-link.w--current:hover {
  color: #858585;
}
.w-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 940px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///home/chronos/u-381d76fe33193f98b522c78a8da993e0f6ff790d/Downloads/New%20Folder/Stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="navigation-bar" data-animation="over-right" data-collapse="medium" data-contain="1" data-doc-height="1" data-duration="600" data-easing="ease-in-out-circ" data-easing2="ease-in-out-circ">
    <div class="w-container">
      <a class="w-nav-brand" href="file:///home/chronos/u-381d76fe33193f98b522c78a8da993e0f6ff790d/Downloads/New%20Folder/Home.html">
        <h1 class="brand-text">Website</h1>
      </a>
      <nav class="nav-menu w-nav-menu" role="navigation">
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="file:///home/chronos/u-381d76fe33193f98b522c78a8da993e0f6ff790d/Downloads/New%20Folder/Home.html">Gallery</a>
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="About">About</a>
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="Contact">Contact</a>
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="Blog">Blog</a>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: check this link:-http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/positioning-content/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because you set `float:right` to the `nav-menu` but you have `w-nav-brand`  which has a text with class `.brand-text` which you set as `display:block` so add `float:left` to the `w-nav-brand`

see snippet below ( check in fullscreen because the img and nav don't fit inside such a small area as the default snippet area . you need to use media queries if you want to reduce the img width or the menu width below a certain viewport width )

or see jsfiddle > [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g7n5ws5p/)

let me know if it helps

```css
.navigation-bar {
  bottom: 0px;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .74);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.brand-text {
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  float: none;
  clear: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease;
  transition: color 700ms ease;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.brand-text:hover {
  color: #858585;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-menu {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.nav-link {
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px none #858585;
  -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease, border 700ms ease;
  transition: color 700ms ease, border 700ms ease;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-link:hover {
  border-style: none;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #858585;
  color: #858585;
}
.nav-link.w--current {
  border-style: none none solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease;
  transition: color 700ms ease;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-link.w--current:hover {
  color: #858585;
}
.w-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 940px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
.w-nav-brand { 
  float:left;
  }
```

```html
 <section class="navigation-bar" data-animation="over-right" data-collapse="medium" data-contain="1" data-doc-height="1" data-duration="600" data-easing="ease-in-out-circ" data-easing2="ease-in-out-circ">
    <div class="w-container">
      <a class="w-nav-brand" href="file:///home/chronos/u-381d76fe33193f98b522c78a8da993e0f6ff790d/Downloads/New%20Folder/Home.html">
        <h1 class="brand-text">Website</h1>
      </a>
      <nav class="nav-menu w-nav-menu" role="navigation">
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="file:///home/chronos/u-381d76fe33193f98b522c78a8da993e0f6ff790d/Downloads/New%20Folder/Home.html">Gallery</a>
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="About">About</a>
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="Contact">Contact</a>
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="Blog">Blog</a>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </section>
```

Comment: Thank you! This really helps!

Comment: @JoshCorbett Glad i could help. don't forget to accept and/or upvote the answer if this is the correct one

Answer (score 0):

`<h1>` is a block-level element, so it takes up the entire parent width, pushing your nav down.

Float the H1 left and it will work as you want - only within the full screen snippet though!

```css
.navigation-bar {
  bottom: 0px;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .74);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.brand-text {
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease;
  transition: color 700ms ease;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.brand-text:hover {
  color: #858585;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-menu {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.nav-link {
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px none #858585;
  -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease, border 700ms ease;
  transition: color 700ms ease, border 700ms ease;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-link:hover {
  border-style: none;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #858585;
  color: #858585;
}
.nav-link.w--current {
  border-style: none none solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease;
  transition: color 700ms ease;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-link.w--current:hover {
  color: #858585;
}
.w-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 940px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///home/chronos/u-381d76fe33193f98b522c78a8da993e0f6ff790d/Downloads/New%20Folder/Stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="navigation-bar" data-animation="over-right" data-collapse="medium" data-contain="1" data-doc-height="1" data-duration="600" data-easing="ease-in-out-circ" data-easing2="ease-in-out-circ">
    <div class="w-container">
      <a class="w-nav-brand" href="file:///home/chronos/u-381d76fe33193f98b522c78a8da993e0f6ff790d/Downloads/New%20Folder/Home.html">
        <h1 class="brand-text">Website</h1>
      </a>
      <nav class="nav-menu w-nav-menu" role="navigation">
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="file:///home/chronos/u-381d76fe33193f98b522c78a8da993e0f6ff790d/Downloads/New%20Folder/Home.html">Gallery</a>
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="About">About</a>
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="Contact">Contact</a>
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="Blog">Blog</a>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </section>
</body>
```